# Understanding the formula:$ [GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

so as mentioned in the title, I want to understand the formula : $[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n$

So here is what I think it means:

1. GF stands for Galois Field, which means its a finite field
2. $[GF(p^n):GF(p)]$ can be read as $|GF(p^n)|/|GF(p)|$. So its a division of the orders of both finite fields. The order is in between the brackets, so basically its $(p^n)/p$, but this is not the given $n$ as the result. What is wrong here?
3. Now my biggest concern was to what is the reason this formula is convenient? My answer: The closest thing I could connect this formula to is cosets, where $|G|/|H|$ (H subgroup of G) is the number of cosets of the subgroup. So in this case $n$ is the number of cosets of GF(p) in $GF(p^n)$?

Am I going in the right direction here? Am I missing things?

Comment: No, $[GF(p^n):GF(p)]\ne|GF(p^n)|/|GF(p)|$. What's the actual definition?

Comment: I am reading the book "Contemporary abstract algebra" by Gallian. Without a joke, its only giving the formula without an explanation (page 390, if it matters, corollary 1). Well that means I am totally off then :)

Comment: I don't know what formula you're talking about in your comment. In any case you haven't answered my question. What's the definition of $[E:K]$?

Comment: Simple, its not defined. As is stated in point 2, that is what I think it should mean. Which apparently is not the case.

Comment: If it's actually not defined you need to find the definition somewhere - using what you think it "should be" is not going to work. Hmm, where could we find this? The book does  say we're talking about fielld extensions, right? So search for "field extension" or "extension field"....

Comment: Since you were aware that the book is talking about field extensions I am gonna assume that you have the book. When looking at page 148, it is clearly stated (corollary 1) what the definition is of |G|/|H|. Therefore my idea to what it should be (hence point 2). Going from this start point 3 seems logic. Since I run in some contradictions something must be off therefore the question. Chapter 22 is only talking about fields and not about extensions. Therefore the direct link of thinking about field extensions from solely a statement is strange.

Comment: No, I don't have the book. The notation $[E:K]$ arises when $E$ is an extension field of $K$. I don't see what the "definition" of $|G|/|H|$ has to do with this -  the  question is what's the definition of $[G:H]$. Maybe II can explain if you tell me what corollary 1 says...

Comment: Ah let me guess: Corollary 1 says that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$, right? If so, that has nothing to do with the current quuestion; $[E:K]\ne|E/K|$. (It's true but  irrelevant that $|GF(p^n)/GF(p)|=p^n/p$.)

Comment: Ah! I bet II see the problem. Assuming my guesses above are correct, the problem is overloaded standard notation. If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $G/H$ refers to the quotient group. Alas when people say "$E/K$ is a field extension" that means just that $K$ is a subfiield of $E$, has nothing to do wiith quotient groups.

Comment: haha, your second guess is correct. So many notations! I got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n$ denote the degree of the extension field $GF(p^n)$ over $GF(p)$ **not** order of $GF(p^n)$ over order of $GF(p)$

Degree means the dimension of $GF(p^n)$ over $GF(p)$. Here the dimension is $n$

Comment: Not it is not a base.

Comment: @Wuestenfux: I agree.. But $GF(p^n)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p^n $ as additive group over $\Bbb Z_p$, so $\{(1,0,0..),(0,1,0,...), \cdots (0,0,...,1)\}$ is a basis

Comment: @ChinnapparajR What does "additive group over $\;\Bbb Z_p\;$" mean? And you cannot forget the ring structure of that field, of course. The dimension you mention is of $\;GF(p^n)\;$ as *a vector space over the field* $\;\Bbb Z_p\;$ . Perhaps a clearer way to denote these fields is $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ ...

Comment: If $V$ is a vector space over $F$ of dimension $d$ then $|V|=|F|^d$. So $p^n=p^d$.

Answer (score 0):

This means you have a finite field with the number of elements (=order) $p^n$, this field can be turned into a linear (=vector) space. In this vector space the scalars are elements of the subfield of this field $GF(p^n)$, prime subfield of order $p$.

The dimension of this vector space is $n$.